# C# regexp for nested tags

Tags: c#, regex, nested, regex-negation

Let's start with little example; I have the following text:

> [[ some tag [[ with tag nested ]] and again ]]

I'd like to match **[[ with tag nested ]]** but not **[[ some tag [[ with tag nested ]]** . Simple

```
\[\[(?<content>.+?)\]\]
```

obviously didn't work. So I created regexp:

```
\[\[(?!.*?\[\[.*?\]\].*?)(?<content>.+?)\]\]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't match anything using C# (with MatchOptions.SingleLine), while PHP's preg_match works perfectly.

Any clues/ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I got no problem running your regex in C# with SingleLine option.  It returns [[ with tag nested ]] correctly.  Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm not certain I see the problem. I created a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` using your second pattern and the `RegexOptions.Singleline` then called `Match` on your example string. It came back with one capture of "[[ with tag nested ]]".

Comment: @Harry: Try it with this input: `[[ outer1 [[ nested1 ]] outer2 [[ nested2 ]] outer3 ]]`.  If I understand the question correctly, it should match `nested1` and `nested2`, but it only matches `nested2`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but I simplified the example so the expected result would be easier to understand. Supprisingly, the example provided succeded with the regexp... but not the real subjects. Alan is right, I wanted to match all nested tags. Thank you all for the time spent on help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way that I know of to find *just one of the innermost* brackets is this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^.*(\[\[(.*?)\]\])", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This works because it finds the *last* `[[` (so there are no more `[[` after it, so it can’t contain any nested tags) and then the immediately following `]]`. Of course, this assumes well-formedness; if you have a string where the start/end brackets don’t match up properly, this can fail.

Once you’ve found the innermost bracket, you could remove it from the input string:

```
input = input.Remove(match.Groups[1].Index, match.Groups[1].Length);
```

and then repeat the process in a while loop until the regular expression no longer matches.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not produce what I (and you probably) wanted to: it matches  from the first [[ .

Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: @Avaer: No, it doesn’t. It works just fine. Have you tried it? If you think it fails, please provide an example input for which it fails.

Comment: I owe you an apologise, I did not observe the content of Groups[1], but in my rush just checked Value. It does work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Would this be a valid match?

```
[[ with [ single ] brackets ]]
```

If not, this regex should do:

```
 \[\[(?<content>[^][]*)\]\]
```

`[^][]` matches any character that's not `[` or `]`.  If single braces *are* allowed, try this:

```
\[\[(?<content>(?:(?!\[\[|\]\]).)*)\]\]
```

`(?!\[\[|\]\]).` matches any character, but only after making sure it's not the start of a `[[` or `]]` sequence.

Comment: @Avaer: So does mine, and mine is simpler.

Comment: @Timwi, I prefer Alan's suggestion. Perhaps yours is simpler in the sense that the regex is shorter, but figuring out why it works (because the first `.*` consumes the entire line, and then back-tracks to the last `[[`) is not that intuitive. Besides, your proposition does not handle cases like `aaa [[ bbb ccc ]] [[ ddd`.

Comment: @Bert: The example you gave is handled by my regex just fine. Have you tried it? — Also, I’m amused how you think this one here is easier to figure out; it’s hideous in comparison :)

Comment: @Timwi: Try it with the example I used in another comment: `[[outer1[[nested1]]outer2[[nested2]]outer3]]`.  Using the `Matches()` method, your regex captures only `nested2`, while mine captures `nested1` and `nested2` as desired.  I agree it's hideous, but it's as simple as it can be and still meet the requirements.

Comment: @Alan: As I mentioned in my answer, it finds *just one of the innermost brackets*, and if you want to match all of them, you can always use a while loop. I can’t think of a reasonable usecase in which you want *only* innermost brackets *and yet all of them*, so in 99% of the cases your `Matches` approach *still* requires a while loop.

Comment: @Timwi: I agree, but it seems to be exactly what the OP wants.  But if I needed to match bracket pairs with other bracket pairs nested inside them to unknown depth (and I had to use a regex), I'd use .NET's balancing groups ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition ) -- but I wouldn't enjoy it.  *That* regex would be uglier than all the regexes offered so far, **combined**. :-/

Comment: @Bart: Timwi's right, his regex would handle that input okay.  It's the *OP's* regex that would choke on it.

Comment: @Timwi, my apologies: I didn't look at your answer too closely!